# How can I append a column to an inner SQL statement?

Tags: oracle, migration, insert

I have two tables that have the same structure except one has an additional column that should be auto-incremented.  Sequence and trigger are defined.

I want to copy all data from one table to another using this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO A_WITH_ADDITIONAL_COLUMN
SELECT * FROM A;
```

But I'm getting error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Which is fine because there is one more column in the target table.

How do I append an additional NULL at the beginning of every row of the source table in order to be able to fill the target WITHOUT enumerating all columns of the source table in the query?

Comment: Of course it is is a VERY POOR practice to ever do an insert without specifying the columns names. VERY BAD things can happen if people change the table structure. Please do not use SQL antipatterns in your coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple:

```
INSERT INTO A_WITH_ADDITIONAL_COLUMN
    SELECT null, A.* FROM A;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO A_WITH_ADDITIONAL_COLUMN (newcol, col1, col2, col3,...)
    SELECT NULL, A.col1, A.col2,a.col3,..... FROM A;
```

Should do what you're asking.

Comment: please read the question once again...

Comment: little harsh as the edit to the question to add that constraint coincided with me typing my answer, but that's life.

Comment: @stuart: You can also edit your answer. Or delete it.

Comment: As it happens this is the correct answer whether it was what the OP wanted to hear anyway. It is a SQL antipattern to use select * or fail to enumerate the columns in an insert statement.